# How to use dyanamic linq in wcf?

Tags: wcf, linq, dynamic

I am using linq-to-entity to retrieve data dynamically and created a method as follows:

```
public List<object> getDynamicList(string tablename, List<string> colnames)
{
    try
    {
        var query = DynamicQueryable.getDynamicData(dbcontext, tablename, colnames);
        List<object> objQueryable = new List<object>();
        object obj = query.AsQueryable();
        objQueryable.Add(obj);
        return objQueryable;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleError(ex);
    }
}
```

this method in wcf service internally refers dynamic class given in LINQ samples (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Samples\1033)by MSVS2010.

when i am passing tablename,columns dynamically it does but on client side,while consuming that method it gives error-   The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.
does wcf gives issue with iqueryable return type ?

please suggest......

Comment: Please post the entire error message you're seeing, including the error message and stack trace.  This will make it much easier to understand what problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into WCF Data Services aka oData Services

Comment: Unable to cast the type 'DynamicClass1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

Try using returning ToList() instead because Linq uses concept of Deffer Loading which means when at client side ToList or Result is being accessed it tries to connect to Server for getting result and it is where it would be getting failed. It is recommended when you use such kind of ORM you detach your objects and send result to client.

Comment: now im gettin error as - Unable to cast the type 'DynamicClass1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.